# Display logged in username after successful login not updating div in Angular 8

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to show logged in user's name in the header navbar after a successful login but for some reason it refuses to appear in the navbar. App is in Angular 8 .Console log outputs it correctly.

So far code is like below:

**--login component**

```
Login(user) {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.userForm.invalid) {
  return;
}

const userData = {username : this.userForm.get('username').value, password: this.userForm.get('password').value};
this.authService.authenticate(userData).subscribe((result) => {
if (result) {
if (result.msg === 'ERROR:LOGIN_FAILED') {
  this.authFailed = true;
  } else {
   this.authFailed = false;
   this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
   this.authService.saveUserDetailsToLocalStorage(result);
   this.authService.setUserLoggedInStatus(result);

 }
} else {
 console.log('ERROR:LOGIN_FAILED');
}
}, (err) => {
 console.log(err);
});
}
```

**-- header.html**

```
 <div>Logged in as  {{ userName}}</div>
```

**--header component**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  subscription: Subscription;
  emitterService: any;
  userName: any;


constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

  this.authenticationService.getUserLoggedInStatus().subscribe((customObject) => {
  this.userName =  customObject['user_name'];
 });

}
```

**--authentication service**

```
export class AuthenticationService extends BaseApiService {



 @Output() loggedInUser: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor(
 private router: Router,
 httpClient: HttpClient) {
 super(httpClient);
}

authenticate (user): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.post<any>(endpoint + 'login', user, httpOptions).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError<any>('authentication'))
);
}

saveUserDetailsToLocalStorage(user){
 localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
 this.loggedInUser.emit(user);
}


 getUserLoggedInStatus(): Observable<any> {
//console.log('returning' + this.loggedInUser);
  return this.loggedInUser.asObservable();
}

setUserLoggedInStatus(message: any) {
// this.loggedInUser.next(message);
 this.loggedInUser.emit(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest working with `OnInit`, which is a legit Angular Hook you can import from `@angular/core` and then extend your component to use it (I see it's already done).

Instead of making the subscription on the constructor, try making it there.

Also, debug the value you get from the request with some console logging. It's always good to be sure.

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  subscription: Subscription;
  emitterService: any;
  userName: any;

  constructor(
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private router: Router,
     private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.authenticationService.getUserLoggedInStatus()
        .subscribe((customObject) => {
            // Make sure the desired value DOES EXIST!
            console.log(customObject['user_name']);
            this.userName =  customObject['user_name'];
        });
  }

}
```

**Bare in mind**, if the above code provides valid output but does not update the view - it is possibly hidden! Make sure through the Developer tools that the view tree is as intended.

Comment: Thank you @fingeron I did try it in ngOnInit() and console log and the value is definitely there but just would not update it on the header navbar.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code I suggested produces a valid `console.log` result but does not update the component view? Because that is a fundamental Angular behavior

Comment: OK found the issue that was causing this behaviour: In app.component.ts  I wanted to hide the navbar other than login page I had the following logic in ngOnInit() ngOnInit() {
   
   this.router.events
   .subscribe((event) => {
     if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       this.headerFooter = (event.url !== '/login')
     }
   });
  }  and in app.component.html I had <app-header *ngIf="headerFooter"></app-header> As soon as I took it out all seems to be working fine. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @snowflakes74 so the view was updated, but hidden? That's a relief. Other option was a framework bug! I will update my answer with that possibility for future references.

Comment: Yes that is correct it is all working now.Thank you